# Spring's UriComponentsBuilder.queryParam issue

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have recently switched to Spring for consuming REST API calls hosted by ServiceNow.

I am building my URI as below:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUrl.toString());
logger.info("URI before Query Param: " + builder.build().encode().toUri());
builder.queryParam("sysparm_limit", "2000000");
builder.queryParam("sysparm_offset", "0");
builder.queryParam("sysparm_exclude_reference_link", "true");
//this line is the issue because there is a = sign here
builder.queryParam("sysparm_query=user_name", snUser.getUser_name());
logger.info("URI after Query Param: " + builder.build().encode().toUri());
```

The output of this code is:

```
INFO: URI before Query Param: https://sandbox.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user
INFO: URI after Query Param: https://sandbox.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user?sysparm_limit=2000000&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_query%3Duser_name=AX0011
```

The problem is with the final builder.queryParam. I am getting output as this:

```
sysparm_query%3Duser_name=AX0011
```

but what I want is:

```
sysparm_query=user_name=AX0011
```

So that eventually the final URI looks like this:

```
INFO: URI after Query Param: https://sandbox.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user?sysparm_limit=2000000&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_query=user_name=Z001NR6
```

---

So I tried replacing,

```
builder.queryParam("sysparm_query=user_name", snUser.getUser_name());
```

by:

```
builder.query("sysparm_query=user_name=" + snUser.getUser_name());
```

which changed the original output from:

```
INFO: URI after Query Param: https://sandbox.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user?sysparm_limit=2000000&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_query%3Duser_name=Z001NR6
```

to:

```
INFO: URI after Query Param: https://sandbox.service-now.com/api/now/v1/table/sys_user?sysparm_limit=2000000&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true&sysparm_query=user_name%3DZ001NR6
```

Notice how sysparm_query%3Duser_name=Z001NR6 changed to sysparm_query=user_name%3DZ001NR6

Is ther anyway to see a = instead of %3D in the output?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The param looks quite strange - however - you can add it manually using the `UriComponentsBuilder#query` method:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl("https://example.com/api/")
            .queryParam("param1", "12345")
            .queryParam("param2", "abc")
            .query("query=username=JOE");

System.out.println(builder.build().toString()); 
// produces https://example.com/api/?param1=12345&param2=abc&query=username=JOE

System.out.println(builder.build().encode().toString());
// produces https://example.com/api/?param1=12345&param2=abc&query=username%3DJOE
```

Manual concatenation:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder
            .fromHttpUrl("https://example.com/api/")
            .queryParam("param1", "12345")
            .queryParam("param2", "abc");
// the parameter has to be properly url-encoded manually (not shown here)
String uri = builder.build().encode().toString() + "&query=username=JOE";

System.out.println(uri);
// produces: https://example.com/api/?param1=12345&param2=abc&query=username=JOE
```

Comment: I know the query looks odd but that is how it is. In .query("query=username=JOE") the value of JOE is parameterized can I replace by snUser.getUser_name(). I know I can create a string concatenation to achieve this, but is there a default method in the UriComponentBuilder?

Comment: No, there is no default method available. But go ahead with string-concatenation (the java compiler will optimize this anyways to a `StringBuilder`)

Comment: I incorporated the change suggested by you and it did not produce the desired effect. Is there anything that I am missing here? I have modified the original post to reflect it.

Comment: Yes, I have used it `builder.build().encode().toUri()`: 

    `response = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, snHttpEntity, String.class);`

Comment: I'm afraid you need to encode your strange query-param manually.

Comment: Can you please elaborate that a little bit more? How would i do that?

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I was trying to avoid this. May be I should just stick to string concatenations then :-/
`StringBuilder baseUrl = new StringBuilder().append(configuration.getSecureHttp())
    .append(configuration.getHostName()).append(configuration.getSearchAndUpdateUserTableNameBulk())
    .append("sysparm_limit=2000000&sysparm_offset=0&sysparm_exclude_reference_link=true")
    .append("&sysparm_query=user_name=").append(snUser.getUser_name());`

Answer (score 0):

The query component of a URL is frequently used to carry information in `key=value` pairs; you could think of this as a `Map<String, String>`. In this case, `=` and `&` are special characters that delimit these pairs, and they must be encoded when they form part of the `key` or the `value` to ensure that anything reading the query string this way is able to parse it properly.

In your case, how you use the `builder` depends on how you would want to retrieve your data later on. There are two options:

```
// Building the URL:
builder.queryParam("sysparm_query=user_name", snUser.getUser_name());
// URL contains ...&sysparm_query%3Duser_name=AX0011

// Reading the parsed query map:
Map<String, String> query = ...
String data = query.get("sysparm_query=user_name");
// value is AX0011
```

Or

```
// Building the URL:
builder.queryParam("sysparm_query", "user_name=" + snUser.getUser_name());
// URL contains ...&sysparm_query=user_name%3DAX0011

// Reading the parsed query map:
Map<String, String> query = ...
String value = query.get("sysparm_query");
// value is user_name=AX0011
```

In a correctly encoded URL, one of the `=` will always be encoded as `%3D`. Using a `UriComponentsBuilder` ensures that your URLs will be correctly encoded and that anything reading your URLs will be able to do so properly without data loss.