# Having queryParam with "+" using UriComponentsBuilder

Tags: java, spring, rest

Based on question [Spring's UriComponentsBuilder.queryParam issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135344/springs-uricomponentsbuilder-queryparam-issue), what if a query parameter has a plus ("+") in its value? By default, a plus will not encoded. Why and how can I force this?

In my example, I want to use da ISO-coded timestamp and I need to encode the plus, because the other endpoint will interprete the "+" as a space (" ") and this breaks by timestamp.

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl("https://example.com/api/")//
        .queryParam("date1", "2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00") //
        .query("date2=2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00");

System.out.println(builder.build().toString());
// produces https://example.com/api/?date1=2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00&date2=2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00

System.out.println(builder.build().encode().toString());
// produces https://example.com/api/?date1=2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00&date2=2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00
```

The expected result should encode the plus sign like `2020-10-05T08%3A20%3A00.000%2B02%3A00` or at least `2020-10-05T08:20:00.000%2B02:00` with `%2B`.

Comment: I found out, the problem might be later when using the ```RestTemplate```. I tried replace hard coded the "+" but after using "```restTemplate.exchange(...)```", my "%" was then quoted to ```%20```.

Comment: I found a solution... should search better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676060/resttemplate-exchange-does-not-encode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use DefaultUriBuilderFactory to encode the query values as such:

```
String baseUrl = "https://example.com";
        DefaultUriBuilderFactory uriBuilderFactory = new DefaultUriBuilderFactory(baseUrl);

        String uri = uriBuilderFactory.uriString("/api/")
                .queryParam("date1", "{date1}")
                .build("2020-10-05T08:20:00.000+02:00").toString(); // https://example.com/api/?date1=2020-10-05T08%3A20%3A00.000%2B02%3A00
```

Comment: @MichaelLindner I have edited the answer, so you can try it out that way, if that output format better suit your needs

Comment: Your solution alone works. Form now, I think the problem might be later... when using the RestTemplate. It looks like, that this also encode the query.

Back to the problem: The "+"  will not encoded, because it is a valid character. But in my use case, the "+" is not a encoded " ".